# Where would I post a question about features in music videos?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Recently, I have been listening to a lot of music, and occasionally watching the videos that go with the songs. I have a question about a symbolic item in a particular artist's videos. Where would I ask this question?

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a question for [Music Fans Stack Exchange](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/). It's not explicitly mentioned in their Help Center article [What topics can I ask about here?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), but IMHO it's close enough.

> Ask about:
>
> - The history of songs and musicians/bands/artists/composers/songwriters/etc.
> - Song meanings and the origins of lyrics
> - Terminology used in the music industry
> - Use, explanation, and history of music technology, devices, and media
> - Information about music memorabilia and the collection of it (e.g. “How rare is X?”)